# Is it possible to create a multiline string?

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script

I´m trying to create a multiline string in Google Apps Scrtip, something like this in Javascript:

```
var temp = \`Hello
             World!\`;
```

I have a text that I want to analyze but I don't want to pre-process it.

Is it possible?

Comment: Looks like this type of literals is not supported by Google apps script. You still can use `var temp = "Text\n\[LINEBREAK]                     here"` if you need to wrap long literals.

Answer (score 8):

If, for example, you had a real long string that extended out past the right margin in the code editor, and you wanted to put it on multiple lines *in the editor* so that you don't need to scroll to the right to read it, but still want the string to be analyzed as one long string, then you can use:

```
var a = 'some text\
 more text here\
 third line.';
```

The above text in the variable `a` will print as one line.

If you are using V8, then you can use commas at the end of each line.

```
var a = 'some text,
 more text here,
 third line.';
```

If you want to cause the string to wrap, in something like an email, or a dialog box, you can use the non-printing newline control characters `\n`

```
var t = 'first line \nsecond line \nthird line';
```

The above string in the variable `t` will print on three lines.

Note that I did not put any space after `\n` or the next line would start with a space.

If you are using HTML, then you can use `<br>`

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible to use the V8 runtime for google scripts.

This allows you to use the javascript [multi-line strings](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#multi-line_strings) in your google scripts.

Here's how to [enable the V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).